# If I uninstall git completely from my Windows 10, will it have any effects that I should be worried about?

Tags: git, git-bash

I need to uninstall `Git bash`, `Git` from my system and install it back again.

Comment: Mostly no. You just install them back again. Take care of your repositories and your `.gitconfig` file. Nothing else to worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't affect your global git config (`%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`), and your existing repositories.

Don't forget you can actually have as many version of Git you want simply by uncompressing a portable archive anywhere you want, and adjusting your `%PATH%` to it.
See [`Git for Windows releases`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), like for instance [`PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe).